# Console Errors with Angular Material and meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, material-design, angular-material

Im using meteor to build a simple application based on the examples provided here:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

When complied with meteor and with the relevant packages installed (angular-material, angular, angular-animate etc).

However, and I have tried this on two computers with different installs, I am consistently getting this error in the chrome console when the website is compiled (it does so without errors in the meteor console). It then does not switch between tabs and the errors appear with each click.

I looked at the solutions here, but I don't understand how this effects me as I am using meteors package manager..

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11658

```
    TypeError: runner.setHost is not a function
    at angular-animate.js:2686
    at Scope.$digest (angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:15961)
    at Scope.$apply (angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:16175)
    at angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:17942
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:5567)
    at angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:5844(anonymous function) @ angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:12535(anonymous function) @ angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:9307Scope.$digest @ angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:15963Scope.$apply @ angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:16175(anonymous function) @ angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:17942completeOutstandingRequest @ angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:5567(anonymous function) @ angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:5844
angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:12535 TypeError: animationRunner.done is not a function
    at Array.triggerAnimationStart (angular-animate.js:3075)
    at nextTick (angular-animate.js:423)
    at scheduler (angular-animate.js:393)
    at angular-animate.js:3087
    at Scope.$digest (angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:15961)
    at Scope.$apply (angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:16175)
    at angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:17942
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:5567)
    at angular_angular.js?hash=c17a5a9…:5844
```

main.html

```
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>


<body ng-app= 'myApp'>
<div ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="three">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
</div>
</body>
```

main.css:

```
    import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import ngMaterial from 'angular-material';
//import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';
//import ngAria from 'angular-aria';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same trouble myself.

Updating my version of angular from 1.48 to 1.5.3_1 fixed this for me.

From command line:

```
meteor update angular:angular
```

Running that also updates the dependent animate and sanitize packages.